# Password contains special characters not saved correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, devise

**Update: Fixed by setting config.pepper in devise.rb**

I use Rails 4 and devise 3.4.1 . I built API to register and authenticate user. Clients that use my API are emberJS web app, IOS App and Android App, POST MAN Chrome app for development.

If i registered user with password contains special characters from POST MAN  the user registered successfully and log in successfully. But when i register user from other clients the user registered successfully but can't log in again.

I checked the following points:

1- I checked request headers and same for all clients. (true)

2- I used rails debugger to ensure that server received password correctly.(true)

3- I have 3 environments development, staging, production. problem exist in staging and production but it works at development.

Comment: Some encoding problem, maybe?

Comment: But server received password correctly ??